# Statistic counter auto refresh div and mysql query

Tags: jquery, refresh

We are building live statistics counter, refreshing numbers every 10sec. (similar like stackoverflow questions counter). We have simple html page, we tried to embed php and tried to use jquery, but no success. Any help? Thanks

```
<html>
    <script> 
        var auto_refresh = setInterval(
            function() {
                $('#stats').fadeOut('fast').fadeIn("fast");
            },
            10000
        );
    </script>
    <div id="stats">
        <?php
            global $conn;
            $query="SELECT count(*) as total FROM posts WHERE type='update'";
            $query2="SELECT count(*) as total FROM members WHERE USERID>0";
            $postnum = mysql_query($query);
            $posts = mysql_result($postnum,0);  
            $chanid = mysql_query($query2);
            $channels = mysql_result($chanid,0);    
            print "<div id='statnr'><h6> $channels </h6><h1>channels </h1> </div>"; 
            print "<div id='statnr'><h6> $posts </h6><h1>posts </h1> </div>";
        ?>
    </div>
</html>
```

Comment: var_dump $conn, $postNum, $chanid and $channels and return the results here.

Answer (score 0):

you're only fading the stats div out an in again. you have to make an ajax call to the php file getting the new data.

```
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
    function() {
        $.ajax(
            url:"counter.php",
            success:function(data){
                $('#stats').fadeOut('fast', function(){ 
                    $(this).html(data).fadeIn('fast'); 
                });
            }
        )
    },
    10000
);
```

Comment: I tried to move php script part to file counter.php and change script part as described. As result counter disappear - I suppose there should be some print or echo left in html part...

Comment: $(this).html(data).fadeIn('fast'); should print the data (content of the php file) to #stats and fade it in again. try alert(data); before this. does it alert anything? or maybe give the link to your page if possible.